# Debugging an app on device using android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to debug an android app by running it on a device using android studio. I want to see all the values in the variables but in the variable window of the debug panel its only showing application is running. How can I see all the variable values. Even breakpoints aren't showing me any values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Start emulator or attach your device to the computer
3. Set one breakpoint or more
4. Run your project in debug mode (shortcut: `Shift+F9`)
5. Perform action, which will go into your breakpoint
6. In the bottom of the screen you should see "Debug" tab and you can click on it
7. In the "Debug" tab, you should see "Debugger", "Console" and "Logcat" tab
8. Click on "Debugger" tab and you should see your application in debug mode
9. Now you can view value of the variables and so on
10. You can also set "watches" for your variables and objects in "Watches" window
11. In the newest version of Android Studio from Canary Channel or IntelliJ IDEA, you can see values of the variables inside the code while debugging

I'm attaching screenshot of Android Studio during debugging of one of my open-source applications.

Please, open it in a separate window or web browser tab, to see more details.

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Regards,

Piotr

Comment: Thanks a ton you r the best